# How to tell which architecture is a ruby version for?

Tags: ruby, windows, devkit

I am new to ruby development thanks to Jekyll, and want to install the Ruby DevKit for an existing installation of Ruby.
The machine I am using has the following version:

`ruby 2.1.6p336 (2015-04-13 revision 50298) [x64-mingw32]`

This was installed with chocolatey package manager, but, from seeing the name, it is not self-evident to me whether this ruby version supports x64 or x86 architectures.

Is that ruby version x64 or x86?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That is the 64-bit version.

The `x64-mingw32` is `arch-platform` format.

So `x64` architecture on the `mingw32` *platform*.
(*platform* is kind of confusing in this context but `mswin` would be Ruby compiled with the MSVC toolchain.)

The x86 version would be listed as `i386-mingw32`.

I think that chocolatey has a package that will install the DevKit for you as well, but I'm not positive on that.

Comment: Thank you for the prompt answer.
Yes, chocolatey has a package to get the proper DevKit (DevKit2 in this case). its lack of a ruby icon teased me.
Have you got a link at hand that talks about the arch-platform in more depth? It would be neat to have that info in your answer.

Comment: I don't have a link to any information on the matter. Likewise my experiences is anecdotal. But I do know it's origin is from cross-compiler  naming conventions.